# Checking if element was shown with webdriverio

Tags: javascript, webdriver-io

I want to click an element on my website, and check if a modal has appeared. How can I get style's attribute with webdriverio library?

I have something like that:

```
var webdriverio = require('webdriverio');
var client = webdriverio.remote(settings).init()
    .url('http://example.com')
    .setValue('#email', 'email')
    .setValue('#password', 'password')
    .click('#loginButton')
    .pause(1500)
    .click('#menuTab')
    .pause(1500)
    .click('a[href="#newFolder"]')
    .pause(1500)
    .then(function () {
        var display = webdriverio.getCssProperty('#newFolder', 'display')
        assert.equal(display, 'block');
        done();
    })
    .end();
```

But it doesn't work, I cannot fetch the `display` attribute here. How should I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using browser.switchTab([windowHandle]); to move command to modal. If it is native JavaScript pop-up then try using browser.alertText([text]); etc